# Draw vertical line in the middle of a line chart (indicator)

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using a chart library called [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) and I am very pleased with it. However, I want to draw a thick vertical line (as a background, not as data) serving as an indicator in the the middle of the line graph. How can I do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the `LimitLine` class to acheive this.

Basically, that class allows you to **draw a customizeable line to a specified position on the y-axis** in the chart and add a description to it.

After creating the line, you need to assign it to an `XAxis` or `YAxis`.

For more details, have a look at the [**documentation**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/The-Axis#limit-lines). You can find limitlines it on the bottom of the page.

Also, this example class shows how to use them: https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/main/java/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/LineChartActivity1.java

**UPDATE**: Now LimitLines can be assigned to any axis!

Comment: Thank you, this will create a horizontal line at the specified y position. What I want is an vertical line at the middle (graphwidth/2) of the graph, but limit lines cannot be assigned to an x-axis.

Comment: Sorry, I misread. What you described is not possible with limit lines then. You will have to modify the library itself to achieve this. I will consider adding vertical lines in a future update!

Comment: Did vertical lines ever get added? I see that sometimes when I touch the graph a verticle line is drawn. Can I hook in to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can draw verctical lines on your graphic using *Highlight* class. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42852833/4361772